# document.execCommand is not a function in vue test utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

Vue testing with vue-test-utils with Jest, gives errors when exec copy command

document.execCommand is not a function.
How can I resolve it?

This is code snippet in component source.

```
   copyToClipboard(){
     document.execCommand('copy');
    }
```

And here I had writen test like this;

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('*****.vue', () => {
let wrapper;
beforeAll(()=>{
wrapper = shallowMount(***, {attachToDocument:true, store, localVue});
})

it('should render correct content', () => {
wrapper.vm.copyToClipboard();
);
}
```

Comment: how are you creating the document object in jest? are you using any libraries like jsdom?

Comment: I had uploaded code here.

Comment: like @stephen has mentioned jsdom doesn't support execCommand and test-utils uses jsdom. so your only luck will be puppeteer

Comment: can you upload code that tests copytoClipboard method using puppeteer?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're using jsdom for the tests? In which case `execCommand` is [not supported](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1539).

Jest [doesn't support](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3940) environments such as headless Chrome, but you may have some success using [Puppeteer](https://medium.com/ovrsea/headless-browser-testing-with-jest-and-puppeteer-2cf7d04f4af5)